# Refresh QTableWidget automatically possible?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

QTableWidget(in my code, ipTable) Item come from test_data.txt.
But test_data.txt file change in every 3seconds.
I want refresh the table automatically..

How can I update QTableWidget automatically..?

This is my code.

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "addip.h"

#include <QFile>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimer()));
    timer->start(1000);

    setWindowTitle( "IP List" );

    ui->ipTable->setColumnCount(3);

    refresh_table();
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}


QStringList Dialog::refresh_table()
{
    int field;
    QFile file( "/home/yein/widget/test_data.txt" );

    QStringList title;
    title << "IP" << "Protocol" << "state";

    file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream read(&file);

    ui->ipTable->clear();
    ui->ipTable->setRowCount(0);
    ui->ipTable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(title);

    while(!read.atEnd())
    {
        QString tmp = read.readLine();
        QStringList tmpList = tmp.split( "," );

        ui->ipTable->insertRow(ui->ipTable->rowCount());
        field = ui->ipTable->rowCount() - 1;

        ui->ipTable->setItem( field, IP, new QTableWidgetItem( tmpList[0] ) );
        ui->ipTable->setItem( field, PROTOCOL, new QTableWidgetItem( tmpList[1] ) );
        ui->ipTable->setItem( field, STATE, new QTableWidgetItem( tmpList[2] ) );
    }
    file.close();

    return table;
}

void Dialog::on_btnAdd_clicked()
{
    QString protocol;
    QString IP;
    int res;
    addIP add(this);
    add.setWindowTitle( "Add IP" );
    res = add.exec();

    if( res == QDialog::Rejected )
        return;

    IP = add.getIP();
    protocol = add.getProtocol();

    qDebug() << "IP :" << " " << IP;
    qDebug() << "Protocol : " << " " << protocol;

    write_on_file( IP,protocol );

}

void Dialog::write_on_file( QString IP, QString protocol )
{
    QFile file( "/home/yein/widget/test_data.txt" );

    file.open( QIODevice::Append );

    data[0] = IP;
    data[1] = protocol;
    data[2] = "0";        // init state 0

    QString _str = QString( "%1,%2,%3\n" )
            .arg( data[0] )
            .arg( data[1] )
            .arg( data[2] );

    qDebug() << _str << " ";

    QByteArray str;
    str.append(_str);

    file.write(str);

    file.close();

    refresh_table();
}


void Dialog::on_btnClose_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}

void Dialog::onTimer()
{
    updateRStatusBar();
}

void Dialog::updateRStatusBar()
{
    QDateTime local(QDateTime::currentDateTime());

    ui->clock->setText(local.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use

```
QFileSystemWatcher::fileChanged(const QString &path)
```

and receive a signal, whenever the file is modified. This recommandation depends on how often the file is changed and on how many files you want to watch.

Comment: I add this code in Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
 It works but work once.. am i doing wrong?                                           `watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);
connect(watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT( refresh_table() ));
    watcher->addPath("/home/yein/widget/test_data.txt" );`

Comment: It only works hte first time? Your code looks quite good to me. Are you changing the file? Or do you delete it and recreate it somewhere?